# TextView line bounds mismatched values when started in landscape orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

I have a confusing problem with my textview, after orientation change:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
        android:text="Simple"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_color_drawable"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/><\FrameLayout>
```

when i start app in landscape mode the method `getLineBounds(1,tmpRect)`
results in:

- tmpRect.top = 69

then I change my phone orientation to portrait and results are:

- tmpRect.top = 76

Hovewer after changing back to landscape the results is set to 74(previosuly 69), and both results doesnt change from now on.

The results are 76 and 74 for when starting app in portrait mode.

I'm really curious why is that happening that numbers are diffrent when started in landscape and I will appreciate any help.

Info: my activity have set `android:screenOrientation="sensor"`

Edit: Seems that problem occurs only when using android > 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need two layout while using landscape and portrait, else the value changes. It set to the default value based on the orientation which you create the layout.
If you need to work only in one mode set to

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

or

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Comment: Well i have to work on both modes with only one layout(no land-port diff), and well my problem is simply that the text bounds are invalid only when i start an app, not by entire time, and thats the cause of my problem(land-port-land works bad[ on first land text have invalid bounds,port is good,second land is also good] but when app started in port - landscape works good all the time)